# experience editor check in cshtml if editing or designing is enabled

Tags: experience-editor

I've created some controller views where I added some special styles to my controls and I want to disable these extra styles when the `Editing`, `Designing` or `Control` button is disabled, is it possible to get these values in the controller?

Currently I am checking these two options, but here I need to change this completely into the preview mode to disable my component background styles.

```
Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal && Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor
```

So it would be nice If I could control my implementation with the `Editing` ,`Designing` or `Controls` checkbox

[image]

Comment: Your question needs clarification. You mention Code Behind files and Controller Views - these are two quite separate technologies (MVC and Webforms). What is it, specifically, you're asking?

Comment: @MarkCassidy I've corrected my text above. What I mean was the controller in MVC.

Comment: Which is what I thought. But that only adds to the confusion. You've already listed the code statements that check for these conditions - so what remains as a question? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you would have to process this client-side (JavaScript), since Sitecore does not do a full page refresh when you click on one of these checkboxes.

The client-side flags would be:

- Designing: `Sitecore.Speak.Commands.EnableDesigning.isEnabled`
- Editing: `Sitecore.Speak.Commands.EnableEditing.isEnabled`
- Controls: `Sitecore.Speak.Commands.ShowControls.commandContext.button.attributes.isChecked`
- Field Validation: `Sitecore.Speak.Commands.EnableFieldsValidation.isEnabled`

Comment: yes you are right, didn't think about it that I don't get a page reload on these checkboxes and so I can't use any .net code to activate or deactivate :-/ and I'Ve heared about speak but don't know anything about it. But thx.